# AND OR in a Linq Query

Tags: c#, linq

In a Linq query I need to filter appointments by Date and Local, Date or Local.

So if GivenDate and GivenLocal are not null I need to filter by GivenDate and GivenLocal:

```
appointments.Where(x => x.Date == x.GivenDate && x.Local == x.GivenLocal)
```

If GivenDate is null then the filter would be done by Local:

```
appointments.Where(x => x.Local == x.GivenLocal)
```

And if GivenLocal is null then filter by Date:

```
appointments.Where(x => x.Date == x.GivenDate)
```

Is it possible to do this with one query instead of using IF statements and 3 queries?

Comment: Do it with `if` statements that build up one query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
appointments.Where(x =>
    (x.GivenDate == null || x.Date == x.GivenDate) &&
    (x.GivenLocal == null || x.Local == x.GivenLocal) && )
```

Comment: Yes, that was the logical condition I was looking instead of using ? in the where query ...

Answer (score 0):

appointments.Where(x => ((x.GivenDate != null && x.GivenLocal != null && x.Date == x.GivenDate && x.Local == x.GivenLocal) || (x.GivenDate == null && x.Local == x.GivenLocal ) || (x.GivenLocal == null && x.Date == x.GivenDate)))